# Regular Expression for split string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the string in like below format:

```
var string = "1SS+2d,12SS+7d,13SS+12d";
```

My requirement is split the given string into array with 3 objects like in the following format:

```
var collection = [{ id : 1,
                    connectiontype : "SS",
                    linelength : 7,
                    linetyype: d
                },
                {
                    id: 12,
                    connectiontype: "SS",
                    linelength: 2,
                    linetyype: d
                },
                {
                    id: 12,
                    connectiontype: "SS",
                    linelength: 2,
                    linetyype: d
                },
                {
                    id: 13,
                    connectiontype: "SS",
                    linelength: 12,
                    linetyype: d
                }            

]
```

I have tried  with split method in string object. But it take more looping logic. How to obtain this using RegExp?

Comment: Are `SS` and `d` always going to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

you can use next regular expression to build your object

```
var regexp = /(\d+)(\w+)\+(\d+)(\w+)/;
var arr = string.split(',');
var collection = [];
var result;
for ( var key in arr ){
    result = regexp.exec(arr[key]);
    collection.push({
        id : result[1],
        connectiontype : result[2],
        linelength : result[3],
        linetyype: result[4]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `split` to split each item using comma, then you can use regex to parse each item to create the object:

```
var string = "1SS+2d,12SS+7d,13SS+12d";
var regex = /(\d+)(\w+)\+(\d+)(\w+)/;
var match = regex.exec(string);

var collection = [];

var items = string.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var match = regex.exec(item);

    collection.push({
        id: match[1],
        connectiontype: match[2],
        linelength: match[3],
        linetyype: match[4]
    });
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DFMv9/)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string then loop over it. I've assumed that `SS` and `d` are going to be the same in each object but YMMV.

```
var r = /^(\d+)SS\+(\d+)d$/;
var collection = [];
str.split(',').forEach(function (el) {
  var m = r.exec(el);
  var obj = {
    id: m[1],
    connectiontype: 'SS',
    linelength: m[2],
    linetyype: 'd'
  };
  collection.push(obj);
});
```